# Dynamic Value in Translation

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

What I am looking to do is have a some way to have a placeholder in my translations file that on runtime when called I can pass in what i18next should replace that placeholder with and I am unable to find documentation on this.

```json
// translations

{
  “label”: “Message has {{count}} total messages”
  “person”: “Welcome {{full_name}} to your new site”
}
```

In the component I am using it I have the following

```
<button aria-label={t(‘label’, { count: total_count})}>
 <svg></svg>
</button>
```

But this is not working. Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called interpolation.

Check out this: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation

Comment: So I am using react and it seems like the react version does not support this way anymore unless I am missing something @adrai

Comment: for sure it supports this, but probably you’re using the Trans component: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Comment: Can I use trans component for an aria label?